What is the correct way to disconnect a DC+DALI line?
Whenever I use a 5-wire cable with DALI, I use a circuit breaker with two additional NO contacts through which the DALI line goes through, so that if there are any problems on the cable side, the DALI connection is also severed.
On the other hand, when using a multi-wire cable for DC+DALI (for example, for a 48VDC track system with DALI support), it's entirely unclear how one would disconnect the DALI lines if we can assume that the AC-DC supply has its own internal circuit breaker-like mechanics (protection from short-circuit and overheating).
The question: how to do this correctly? Should I use additional circuit breakers per-circuit downstream from the AC-DC? Something else?

Disclaimer: I'm not an electrician.
I guess that the answer will strongly depend on your local regulations. For example, I'm based in Czechia, EU, and while I'm well aware of regulations which mandate a physical disconnect with at least a 3mm insulation gap for permanently-wired appliances, both in the L and N wires, I do not think that there's a similar requirement for the DALI line.
What problem are you solving?

It’s not clear what you are trying to protect with the DALI disconnection. Bear in mind DALI allows for multiple PSUs on the same line provided the total current isn’t exceeded and the polarity is the same.

@Martin damage to the cable would be a perfect example

The DALI power supply is current-limited at 250mA. During the regular operation, DALI devices regularly short the bus, that's the way how these devices communicate. There's absolutely no need to add a circuit breaker between "the bus" and "any device".

@JanKundrát damage to the cable would be a perfect example. a permanently fused dali line would make the rest of the dali installation inoperable

I'm afraid that you'll have to describe your concern in much more detail than "cable damage". Once again, the bus itself is designed to be short-circuited many times a second. How would this "cable damage" happen, and how do you hope that your protection circuit saves the cable?

@JanKundrát you're hanging a painting, and a nail or screw goes through it accidentally. the electrical part is shorted and quickly handled by a circuit breaker. the dali part is shorted too (permanently) but there is no breaker and we want to deactivate just this line, not the entire installation

The MCB doesn't guard against a nail going through the cable, it guards against overcurrent or a short circuit. These conditions will only happen if the nail shorts your L to N, or L to PE. There's a number of other scenarios which are "dangerous", but not caught by a MCB. So, if a wire shorts your DA+ to DA-, your DALI bus will be down, but there's no overcurrent, no wire heating, etc. You handle this in the same way as a device malfunction -- you disconnect the affected DALI segment. You could build a star topology with auxiliary MCB contacts, but that's totally an overkill, IMHO.

@JanKundrát that's exactly my point! exactly! you disconnect the affected DALI segment. it explains why I'm asking the question I'm asking.
